# testing an API endpoint with a curl request, GET, with a param

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, curl

I have an API endpoint that looks like this:

```
module Api
  class SomeEndpoint < BaseController

    def index
       ...
        params['product_id']],
      ...
      end
    end
end
```

The route to hit it would be /api/some_endpoint. I also need to send it a params hash. I am trying to just QA this endpoint. How would I send a curl request to it to QA it?

Answer (score 2):

May this help you

```
curl -X GET -F "product_id = 1" https://hostname/some_endpoint
```